# How to choose the EC2 Instance type of an Elastic Beanstalk environment when creating it using awscli?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I've been through all the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/) (I guess). And haven't found a way, yet, to choose which EC2 instance type to use for my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it when you create your environment. (It will overwrite what you selected when you did eb init)

```
eb create --instance_type t2.micro
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html

You can also set it in your .ebextensions/config

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
   InstanceType: t2.micro
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html